# Wireless not working on very old PC on Debian

Tags: debian, wifi

I have this really old [**PC Toshiba Pro L10**](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/discontinued-products/107655/) running on 512 MB on RAM. I installed Debian 32 bit lxde spin off. Everything is working well except the wireless (`no wireless extensions`). Wired network connection works.

My environment is this:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
7.5
$ uname -r
3.2.0-4-686-pae
$ iwconfig
l0       no wireless extensions.
eth0     no wireless extensions.
$ apt-cache policy wireless-tools
wireless-tools:
  Installed: 30~pre9-8
  Candidate: 30~pre9-8
  Version table:
 *** 30~pre9-8 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at <unassigned> (32-bit, prefetchable)
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=05 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel

00:00.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:00.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 82852/82855 GM/GME/PM/GMV Processor to I/O Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82852/855GM Integrated Graphics Device (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 6
    Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 1
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82852/855GM Integrated Graphics Device (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at e0080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 1

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 6
    I/O ports at 1820 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [UHCI])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 6
    I/O ports at 1840 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: uhci_hcd

00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at e0100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=0080
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd

00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 83) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=06, sec-latency=64
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: e0200000-e04fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 24000000-27ffffff

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801DBM (ICH4-M) IDE Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 8a [Master SecP PriP])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 6
    I/O ports at 01f0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 03f4 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 0170 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 0374 [size=1]
    I/O ports at 1810 [size=16]
    Memory at 20000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Kernel driver in use: ata_piix

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    I/O ports at 1860 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus

00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    I/O ports at 1c00 [size=256]
    I/O ports at 1880 [size=64]
    Memory at e0100c00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512]
    Memory at e0100800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: snd_intel8x0

00:1f.6 Modem: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Modem Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [Generic])
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    I/O ports at 2400 [size=256]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: snd_intel8x0m

02:01.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCI1410 PC card Cardbus Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 168, IRQ 10
    Memory at e0400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Bus: primary=02, secondary=03, subordinate=06, sec-latency=176
    Memory window 0: 24000000-27ffffff (prefetchable)
    Memory window 1: 28000000-2bffffff
    I/O window 0: 00003400-000034ff
    I/O window 1: 00003000-000030ff
    16-bit legacy interface ports at 0001
    Kernel driver in use: yenta_cardbus

02:02.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8139/8139C/8139C+ (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff31
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 6
    I/O ports at 3800 [size=256]
    Memory at e0402000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too

02:04.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2741
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at e0401000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://wiki.debian.org/ipw2200 ? You may have to install a "non-free" firmware package.

Comment: @goldilocks what is "non-free"? do I have to buy it from somewhere?

Comment: nvm, i'll google it :)

Comment: It refers to stuff whose licence is not compatible with a [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) licence.  Debian and some of the other major distros have a policy whereby such things are not included in the base repos -- but then they have "non-free" repos you can add to the package manager configuration.

Comment: The famous mnemonic for remembering that "free" and "non-free" don't refer to money is *"It's not free as in beer."* (Richard Stallman).

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much space here to describe to you step by step a possible solution to this little problem, because my time is half gone ... but here I'll give you a link where you have all the information to solve this little problem take a peek and if possible then let us know if you managed to solve this ok! ...
[information to resolve the wireless drive on system...](http://soad1982.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/intel-corporation-prowireless-2200bg.html)

Comment: the link by goldilocks in comment worked. the issue was with my source.list file. try editing your answer according to it.